# GET error /info stompjs angular spring boot

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-websocket

i'm trying to do a simple chat application using websocket in spring boot and angular,
i'm using stompjs i get the error 'GET http://localhost:4200/hello/info?t=1692307507136 404 (Not Found)'

web socket configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer{
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry){
        registry.addEndpoint("/hello").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry){
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");

    }
```

Chat class:

```
@Controller
public class ChatController {
    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/public")
    public String SendMessage(@Payload String message){
        System.out.println(message);
        return message;
    }
}
```

client side:

```
export class ChatComponent implements OnInit{
  StompClient:any
  ngOnInit() {
    let socket=new SockJS("/hello");
    this.StompClient=over(socket);
    let that=this;
    this.StompClient.connect({},function(frame:any){
      that.StompClient.subscribe("/topic/public",function(msg:any){
        console.log(msg)
      })
    })
```